# A single field or 2 fields for "description" and "content" of Article?

Tags: database, database-design, database-development

Say, I want to create a db schema for a blog. So far I've used 2 separate fields for "description" and "content" of Article. But I've seen a lot that usually only a single is used for both. The "description" is everything that goes before a special tag such as "========cut=======" and the whole field is "content". The tag "========cut=======" is cut off when an article is presented to a user.

For me, both approaches are more or less the same. Which one is recommended? Which one do you think is better?

Answer (score 7):

Storing things that are logically two different things as one thing always means that you have to perform extra work when you actually want to treat them as different things. That seems like wasted effort with no gain - two table columns do the job perfectly. You can still retrieve both simultaneously with the appropriate `SELECT` statement, *or* only one of them, as the situation warrants.

Answer (score 1):

How the posts are edited, stored, and displayed are *independent* from each other. Internally, you should use a storage format that is convenient to work with for your application. When you show that content to users, you are free to combine it.

In the blogging software I have written, I decided to keep article contents separate from the description, because:

- not every article has a description.
- sometimes the article consists only of the description, and
- the description may be taken from the article, or may be an independent text.

Due to these requirements, my input format has options such as specifying an independent description, or taking part of the article body until a certain marker tag is found.

Storing description separately from other contents also makes it easier to render only the description, e.g. in a list of articles: I don't have to parse the whole body first. The drawback is that if the description is taken from the body, then I've duplicated that text. When I edit the body, then I need to update the description as well.

But your requirements may be quite different. For example, if the description is always taken from the article body and cannot be an independent text then using such a marker is likely sensible. It may also be sensible to store the whole text as a single database column, but this makes queries more difficult when you only want the description.

Since edits are rare compared to rendering the description, it may be sensible to extract the description whenever the article is updated, and storing the (extracted) content in a separate field from the content. This will not noticeably affect the performance or the storage requirements, but it likely simplifies your application: you only need to deal with extracting the description in one location (when an edit is stored), not in every place where that description is rendered.

Comment: `When I edit the body, then I need to update the description as well.` -- but why don't you make "full_body = description + body"?

Comment: @Kakki because then whenever you want to look at the body, you have to do the `+`

Comment: @Caleth, + is very cheap

Comment: @Kakki Performance doesn't matter that much. What my answer is concerned about is using a data model that is *convenient* to work with in your application. Having to recombine the data when it is edited, rendered, searched, or used in any other manner is inconvenient.